# Equivalent C# code for VB6 calculation using double and currency

Tags: c#, vb6, double

I'd like to know what the C# equivalent of the following VB6 code is that will generate the exact same results:

```
Public Function Moo(o1 As Currency, o2 As Double) As Currency
    Moo = Round((o1 * o2) / 100, 2)
End Function
```

Before you answer with `Math.Round(o1 * (decimal)o2 / 100, 2)`, consider the following test case:

o1 = 1450
o2 = 1.15

The VB6 function returns 16.67 and that C# code returns 16.68.

Next option: `(decimal)Math.Round((double)o1 * o2 / 100, 2)`

That generates the same result but then there's this test case:

o1 = 1570
o2 = 1.15

Now, the VB code generates 18.06 but the C# generates 18.05.

I understand the reasoning behind why this is happening and why one should never use `double` for calculations that require accuracy and that the VB6 code is doing things it shouldn't. Consider this an academic exercise. Essentially, is it possible to get the following test to pass:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1450, 1.15, 16.67)]
[InlineData(1570, 1.15, 18.06)]
public void MooTest(decimal o1, double o2, decimal expectedValue) {
    var value = {MAGICAL METHOD CODE HERE};
    Assert.Equal(expectedValue, value);
}
```

Comment: Before you make sure C# matches VB6 you should probably make sure [C# matches C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6683059/11683).

Comment: Which argument is `basis` and which is `rate`? Your parameter names don't match the signature.

Comment: After 25 years working with systems in a bank, I would suggest stop using currency type for currency, even more, stop using decimal or float, take everything in long (or byte[] if the long max is reached) as an integer of cents

Comment: What is the result of the calculation before calling `Round` in VB6

Comment: @LeandroBardelli This isn't a case of which one is correct. The requirement under discussion was "it has to match the legacy code regardless of which one is correct"

Comment: I'm not in favor of respect the legacy since it's pretty clear a vb error. In the begin, vb is a language made with C :S

Comment: in one case you have to round up with a 5, in the case you dont. yes you can get the tests to pass if you use example specific ifs, but thats stupid just to get the unit test to pass.

Comment: VB6/VBA's `Round()` uses what's called Banker's Rounding, which is achieved by setting the [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0) flag with .NET's Round().

Comment: @HelO'Ween Math.Round defaults to MidpointRounding.ToEven if you leave it off. I've verified that VB6 and C# both round consistently. Here, I believe it's an issue with how VB6 handles doubles

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Agreed but in many cases "correct" often takes a backseat to "don't rock the boat". All we can do is make a recommendation on how much stuff will cost and leave the final decision to those who pay the bill.

Comment: [Is this the magical method you're looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741404/690141)

Comment: @JimmySmith That looks promising though I'll have to find a Linux equivalent for it

Comment: Ah Linux, I'd go with libc, [getround](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-fegetround) and `fesetround (0)` I believe is what you'd temporarily set